# Fixing airflow in PC case

Tags: fan

So i've got this case -> https://en.sharkoon.com/product/AI7000Glass

It has 3 fans already, 2 front (in), 1 back (out). My problem is that inside this case reside a Ryzen 7 2700X and an RTX 2080.

I benchmarked my RTX 2080 to check something out. All was fine, except one thing.
When my GPU got hotter i started hearing the CPU fans go up in RPM. When GPU got to 73 degrees i wanted to check if its my imagination and it was not. CPU temp was 55+.

The CPU Usage was less than 15% so i'm guessing its an airflow problem here.

My idea is to buy 2 new vents for the top of the case (the only slots i've got left), but my question is... how can i improve the airflow further because i highly doubt that 2 vents throwing the air out would make such a huge difference.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the case, adding vents can actually DECREASE cooling perfornance. You want to be sucking air (generally from the front of the case) and pushing it over the parts before pushing it out, and cutting holes may interfere with this flow.

Assuming the GPU is the issue, have you considered better cooling for it. Also, are your fans all wired so air flows in 1 direction?

Comment: I linked my case, also i edited my question. Its not a components issue. The issue is that the heat from the GPU affects the CPU temp which led me to the idea of poor airflow in the case. All fans are wired and working, 2 from the front sucking air in and the one in the back pushing it out.

Comment: 55 is not hot for a CPU. This is not a ventilation issue. Maybe yiu can change the fan settings in the BIOS?

Comment: 55 is hot when it was at about 12% usage. Now its at 12% and its at 40 degrees (20 minutes after stopping the GPU benchmark). The CPU fan is set on auto and seems to work fine (CPU got to about 65 degrees during the benchmark and dropped fast to 55 due to fans going to 100%).